# Mysql_fetch_row not populating SESSION array with multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Hello Here is my solution as i took some advice about the SQL statement ... thank you all

```
$connection = ConnectionBD();
$tag = $_SESSION['nomUtilisateur'];
$panier= array();
$requete = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cours INNER JOIN elevecours ON cours.idcours = elevecours.IDCours WHERE elevecours.IDEleve= '$tag'",$connection);
$H = 0;
        if(mysql_num_rows($requete) != 0)
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($requete))
            {
                //$panier[] = $row;
                $_SESSION['Panier']['Id'][$H]        = $row[0];
                $_SESSION['Panier']['CodeCours'][$H] = $row[1];
                $_SESSION['Panier']['Titre'][$H]     = $row[2];
                $_SESSION['Panier']['Prealable'][$H] = $row[3];
                $_SESSION['Panier']['NbHeure'][$H]   = $row[4];
                $_SESSION['Panier']['Session'][$H]   = $row[5];
                $_SESSION['Panier']['Credit'][$H]    = $row[6];
                $H ++;
            }
        }
        mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: instead of incrementing `$R` you can just do `$panier[] = ...` and it will give you a continuous, numerical index on the array.

Comment: Did you spot the obvious difference between `while($row = mysql_fetch_row($requete))` and `$resultat = mysql_fetch_row($req);`?

Comment: Hi ! i'm trying to get all row from database to fill $_SESSION['Panier'] as there is 2 row but only fill the first

Comment: in the first set of code or the second?  `mysql_fetch_row` only gets one row at a time (like in your second section of code).

Comment: i would say i try about everything no $R incrementing as gloomy suggest ... try whitout the loop while it always return only 1 row ...

Comment: The second seem's containing all the row as show by var_dump, but in the first when i try to compare the result : if($resultat[$i] == $panier[$j][0]) it doesn't

Comment: my goal is to look into table cours to retreive all data and then look into table IDCours if i have a match then copy all column from cours into $_SESSION['Panier']

Comment: why not have your sql query do that?

Comment: what does `$panier` look like?

Comment: that ***is*** two items...??  you're expecting 2 results, right?  `$panier[0]` is the first thing, `$panier[1]` is the second row/result/thing... `//this is what show var_dump : array(2) { [0]=> array(1)`  (i'm so confused as to what the goal is here...)

Comment: I have to agree with gloomy.penguin on the question being quite confusing. Robyseb How are you even getting data at all? this code should not work. And I will ask again, why not have your sql query do that?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 0):

You need to mysql_fetch_row once per iteration in your loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($req); $i++) {
     $resultat = mysql_fetch_row($req);
     //the rest of your code goes here
}
```

Comment: `if ($resultat!==false) { while( $resultat = mysql_fetch_row($req) ) { ... } } ` is better...

Answer (score 0):

Inside your second foreach loop you are setting $H = 0; and then $H++ inside the same loop, this will not increment properly as the next time it goes over the loop again the $H = 0; statement will result this to 0 and therefore keep overwriting your data until the loop is done and you're left with only one $_SESSION value at the end.

```
                for($j = 0; $j < count($panier); $j++)
                { 

                        if($resultat[$i] == $panier[$j][0])
                        {
                            $H = 0; <-- sets to zero on every interation 
                            $_SESSION['Panier']['Id'][$H] = $result[0];
                            $_SESSION['Panier']['CodeCours'][$H] = $result[1];
                            $_SESSION['Panier']['Titre'][$H] = $result[2];
                            $_SESSION['Panier']['Prealable'][$H] = $result[3];
                            $_SESSION['Panier']['NbHeure'][$H] = $result[4];
                            $_SESSION['Panier']['Session'][$H] = $result[5];
                            $_SESSION['Panier']['Credit'][$H] = $result[6];
                            $H++;
                        }
                }
```

Suggest you move this outside your loop if the intention is to iterate the $H variable.

Comment: `$result` isn't defined anywhere in that code he has up there.  (I'm frustrated)... don't give a solution that contains it.  `$result` is null.  and `$resultat` is a single row, not a 2D array (just, btw)

Comment: giving the benefit of the doubt that $resultat SHOULD be $result the code shouldn't even work at all in the current state. Regardless, the question was why only one session value was populating. the answer points out that he is resetting his index inside his for loop.

Comment: that's not the problem, though.  and in your inner most code, `$result` isn't being incremented, while the `_session` is, so the ultimate plan is just to make `count($panier)` copies of `$result` into `_session`?  there's no way anyone can answer this question until we know... what is in `$panier`?  based on a comment OP said (i think), they expect many rows back, want to compare for something with `$panier` and copy at least 1 row from the db into `_session`.

Comment: the problem is... half their variables are undefined.  they aren't getting multiple results back because they only do `mysql_fetch_row` once and i have no idea how much data they actually want in `_session`... and yeah, like someone said, they should just filter in the query, not with PHP arrays.  but who really knows....

Comment: In the second part of the code posted to the question $panier= array(); which is passed by reference into saveBasket(&$panier, $connection). So let's say that $result = mysql_fetch_row. Then $result[0] would gather the value of the current row array at index 0 and so forth. Not sure what the misunderstanding is? He didn't ask "why is my code not working" he asked "why is my session only storing one value". You make a good point that the question can't be answered from a "fix my code" perspective, but he isn't asking that.

Comment: he didn't ask why he's only storing one result.  he asked why he's getting one result.  it' doesn't matter, it's the same question really.

Comment: The same poster goes on later to say they have 2 rows - "Hi ! i'm trying to get all row from database to fill $_SESSION['Panier'] as there is 2 row but only fill the first" regardless this question is lacking alot of information and it's becoming a complete waste of time. I apologize again for frustrating you...

Comment: Hello ! sorry i had to stop thinking for a while loll, i was getting lost ... i'm getting back on it and tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

these are my testing variables...

```
   $session = array(); 
   $panier = array(array(1,'one'),array(2,'two'),array(3,'three'),);

   $req = array(
         array(1,'one','Titre1','Prealable1','NbHeure1','Session1','Credit1'),
         array(2,'two','Titre2','Prealable2','NbHeure2','Session2','Credit2'),
         array(3,'three','Titre3','Prealable3','NbHeure3','Session3','Credit3'),
         array(4,'four','Titre4','Prealable4','NbHeure4','Session4','Credit4'),
         array(5,'five','Titre5','Prealable5','NbHeure5','Session5','Credit5'),);
```

i wrote the code to not rely on your DB and data exactly, since I don't know what it is... dunno.  switch out some of these lines of code to use your database stuff.

```
   // $req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cours", $connection);  uncomment this line for your code

   if ($req!==false) 
   {
      foreach( $req as $i => $resultat )             // testing row, remove for real
      // while( $resultat = mysql_fetch_row($req) )  // real row, uncomment for you 
      {
         $compare = $resultat[0];  
         // we will be using $compare to see if this row
         // matches one in $panier.. this needs to be changed
         // appropriately.  I don't have enough info to define it....
         // this needs to be a unique field, or it should be 
         // it is going to be used like this:  if($resultat[$i] == $panier[$j][0])

         $result[ $compare ] = $resultat;
      } 

      $hi = 0;  
      foreach( $panier as $index => $panier_row )
      {                        
         $compare = $panier_row[0]; 

         if (isset($result[$compare]))
         {
            $H = 0;

            // change $session to $_SESSION for your code...  
            $session['Panier']['Id'][$hi][$H]        = $result[$compare][0];
            $session['Panier']['CodeCours'][$hi][$H] = $result[$compare][1];
            $session['Panier']['Titre'][$hi][$H]     = $result[$compare][2];
            $session['Panier']['Prealable'][$hi][$H] = $result[$compare][3];
            $session['Panier']['NbHeure'][$hi][$H]   = $result[$compare][4];
            $session['Panier']['Session'][$hi][$H]   = $result[$compare][5];
            $session['Panier']['Credit'][$hi][$H]    = $result[$compare][6];
            $H++;
            $hi++;  
         }
      }        
   }
```

my results show `$session['Panier']['Credit']` as having three things for 1, 2, 3 but not 4 or 5 because they don't match `$panier`.

what is in `$session` at the end of all that:

```
array (
  'Panier' => 
  array (
    'Id' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 1,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 2,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 3,
      ),
    ),
    'CodeCours' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'one',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'two',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'three',
      ),
    ),
    'Titre' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Titre1',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Titre2',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Titre3',
      ),
    ),
    'Prealable' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Prealable1',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Prealable2',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Prealable3',
      ),
    ),
    'NbHeure' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'NbHeure1',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'NbHeure2',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'NbHeure3',
      ),
    ),
    'Session' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Session1',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Session2',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Session3',
      ),
    ),
    'Credit' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Credit1',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Credit2',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'Credit3',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**personally, though... you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and do it like this:**

```
   $session = array(); 
   $panier = array(array(1,'one'),array(2,'two'),array(3,'three'),);

   $req = array(
        array('id'=>1,'var'=>'one','Titre'=>'Titre1','Prealable'=>'Prealable1','NbHeure'=>'NbHeure1','Session'=>'Session1','Credit'=>'Credit1'), 
        array('id'=>2,'var'=>'two','Titre'=>'Titre2','Prealable'=>'Prealable2','NbHeure'=>'NbHeure2','Session'=>'Session2','Credit'=>'Credit2'), 
        array('id'=>3,'var'=>'thr','Titre'=>'Titre3','Prealable'=>'Prealable3','NbHeure'=>'NbHeure3','Session'=>'Session3','Credit'=>'Credit3'), 
        array('id'=>4,'var'=>'fou','Titre'=>'Titre4','Prealable'=>'Prealable4','NbHeure'=>'NbHeure4','Session'=>'Session4','Credit'=>'Credit4'), 
        array('id'=>5,'var'=>'fiv','Titre'=>'Titre5','Prealable'=>'Prealable5','NbHeure'=>'NbHeure5','Session'=>'Session5','Credit'=>'Credit5'),); 


   // $req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cours", $connection); 

   if ($req!==false) 
   {
      foreach( $req as $i => $resultat )             // testing row, remove for real
      // while( $resultat = mysql_fetch_assoc($req) )  // real row, uncomment for you 
                                                       //  mysql_fetch_assoc !!
      {
         $compare = $resultat['id'];  
         // we will be using $compare to see if this row
         // matches one in $panier.. this needs to be changed
         // appropriately.  I don't have enough info to define it....
         // this needs to be a unique field, or it should be 

         $result[ $compare ] = $resultat;
      } 

      foreach( $panier as $index => $panier_row )
      {                        
         $compare = $panier_row[0]; 

         if (isset($result[$compare]))
         { 
            $session[] = $result[$compare];  
         }
      }        
   }
```

and this is `$session`

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'var' => 'one',
    'Titre' => 'Titre1',
    'Prealable' => 'Prealable1',
    'NbHeure' => 'NbHeure1',
    'Session' => 'Session1',
    'Credit' => 'Credit1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'var' => 'two',
    'Titre' => 'Titre2',
    'Prealable' => 'Prealable2',
    'NbHeure' => 'NbHeure2',
    'Session' => 'Session2',
    'Credit' => 'Credit2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'var' => 'thr',
    'Titre' => 'Titre3',
    'Prealable' => 'Prealable3',
    'NbHeure' => 'NbHeure3',
    'Session' => 'Session3',
    'Credit' => 'Credit3',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hello I find the solution and edit my post whit it ... thank you very mutch.